# Jenkins on Windows 2008 R2 SSH

Tags: windows, server

I'm setting up a build server for our team, and ran into an issue.

Starting up Jenkins as a windows service, I immediately see these exceptions in the Error log:

```
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:32 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Beginning extraction from war file
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:32 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: jetty-winstone-2.8
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:35 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:35 AM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog info
INFO: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8999
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:35 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v2.0 running: controlPort=disabled
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:36 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started initialization
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:36 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Listed all plugins
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:36 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Prepared all plugins
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:36 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Started all plugins
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:36 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Augmented all extensions
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:39 AM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
INFO: Loaded all jobs
Sep 18, 2015 9:26:40 AM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error
WARNING: Failed to instantiate Key[type=org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.PageDecoratorImpl, annotation=[none]]; skipping this component
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
  at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.PageDecoratorImpl.<init>(PageDecoratorImpl.java:20)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:65)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1.get(ExtensionFinder.java:428)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder._find(ExtensionFinder.java:390)
    at hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder.find(ExtensionFinder.java:381)
    at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:388)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:349)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:287)
    at hudson.ExtensionList.iterator(ExtensionList.java:156)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.getDescriptor(Jenkins.java:1181)
    at hudson.plugins.disk_usage.DiskUsageProperty.transitionAuth(DiskUsageProperty.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:106)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:176)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:282)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$7.runTask(Jenkins.java:898)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:210)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.<init>(InstanceIdentity.java:62)
    at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.<init>(InstanceIdentity.java:38)
    at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.PageDecoratorImpl.<init>(PageDecoratorImpl.java:21)
    at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.PageDecoratorImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$68618106.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:88)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1058)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:966)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:824)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:436)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at org.jenkinsci.main.modules.instance_identity.InstanceIdentity.<init>(InstanceIdentity.java:60)
    ... 38 more

Sep 18, 2015 9:26:40 AM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error
WARNING: Failed to instantiate Key[type=org.jenkinsci.main.modules.sshd.SSHD, annotation=[none]]; skipping this component
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
```

This leads to a bunch more similar errors caused by this un instantiated key, which was originally caused by this BadPaddingException. I'm not an expert in this sort of stuff but I presume there is something with the way SSH is configured on my server.

Another piece to this is, I can access Jenkins just fine from the localhost, I have granted a port for Jenkins from when remote users access the Jenkins site (we have a specific domain for this machine for external users). However, this doesn't seem to work as for some reason it fails to connect. Running Fiddler it says [Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "xxxxxxx" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known

Like I said earlier, I'm not an expert in this sort of stuff so I'm looking for any pointers or solutions to get started on figuring out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for anyone that runs into this, McAfee was blocking any firewall rules for some reason. I threw Jenkins on Apache Tomcat and it allowed firewall rules to accept traffic only if I put it on port 8080.

Comment: what do you mean you put Jenkins on Tomcat? I have a similar error:  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31530
[JENKINS-31530] Upon a restart, many exceptions including: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException, Guice, Failed to instantiate Windows_slave_installer. - Jenkins JIRA

Comment: Hi, you can run Jenkins as it's own application on Tomcat. You can also try deleting the generated identity key (back that up first) and restarting the server. This happened recently to us.